# Correct Flow for Google OAuth2 with PKCE through Client App to SAAS API Server

Tags: wpf, go, oauth-2.0, pkce

So we are working on a client application in Windows WPF. We want to include Google as a login option and intend to go straight to the current most secure method. At the moment we have spawned a web browser with the following methods to obtain a Authorization Code

```
private async void HandleGoogleLogin() {
        State.Token = null;

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "openid" };

        var request = GoogleOAuthRequest.BuildLoopbackRequest(scopes);
        var listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(request.RedirectUri);
        listener.Start();

        // note: add a reference to System.Windows.Presentation and a 'using System.Windows.Threading' for this to compile
        await Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => {
            googleLoginBrowser.Address = request.AuthorizationRequestUri;
        });

        // here, we'll wait for redirection from our hosted webbrowser
        var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();

        // browser has navigated to our small http servern answer anything here
        string html = string.Format("<html><body></body></html>");
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        var stream = context.Response.OutputStream;
        var responseTask = stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            stream.Close();
            listener.Stop();
        });

        string error = context.Request.QueryString["error"];
        if (error != null)
            return;

        string state = context.Request.QueryString["state"];
        if (state != request.State)
            return;

        string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];


        await APIController.GoogleLogin(request, code, (success, resultObject) => {
            if (!success) {
                //Handle all request errors (username already exists, email already exists, etc)
            } else {
                ((App)Application.Current).UserSettings.Email = resultObject["email"].ToString();
                ((App)Application.Current).SaveSettings();
            }
            attemptingLogin = false;
        });
    }
```

and

```
public static GoogleOAuthRequest BuildLoopbackRequest(params string[] scopes) {
        var request = new GoogleOAuthRequest {
            CodeVerifier = RandomDataBase64Url(32),
            Scopes = scopes
        };

        string codeChallenge = Base64UrlEncodeNoPadding(Sha256(request.CodeVerifier));
        const string codeChallengeMethod = "S256";

        string scope = BuildScopes(scopes);

        request.RedirectUri = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, GetRandomUnusedPort());
        request.State = RandomDataBase64Url(32);
        request.AuthorizationRequestUri = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile{6}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
            AuthorizationEndpoint,
            Uri.EscapeDataString(request.RedirectUri),
            ClientId,
            request.State,
            codeChallenge,
            codeChallengeMethod,
            scope);

        return request;
    }
```

To my understanding, from this point the client app has completed the required portion to have the user login to their google account and approve any additional privileges.

Our API/App server is in GoLang.

```
APIController.GoogleLogin
```

from above sends the CodeVerifier and AuthorizationCode to the GoLang application server to then finish off the OAuth2 Flow.

Is this the correct flow given our client-server setup?
If so, what is the best practice for the Go Server to retrieve a Access Token/Refresh Token and get user information? Should the client app be performing a looping check-in to the app server as the app server will not immediately have the required information to login?

Thanks for the help!